# Independence of two uniformly distributed random variables

Tags: probability, random-variables, uniform-distribution

Let $ X \sim U([-1,1])$ and $ Y = {X^2} $. Are $X$ and $Y$ independent? Why?

So, here I tried to show the independence by checking whether $F_{(X,Y)}(x,y)=F(x) \cdot F(y)$.
And I wrote $$F_{(X,Y)}(x,y)=P(X\le x,Y\le x)=P(X\le x,X^{2}\le x)=P(X\le x,-\sqrt{x}\le X\le \sqrt{x})=P(-\sqrt{x}\le X\le \sqrt{x})  $$
Now, I just need to know am i doing since all right? If not what is wrong, what will you suggest to do to show the independence or dependence.

Comment: $F_{(X,Y)}(x,y) = P(X \leq x, Y \leq y)$ and not $P(X \leq x, Y \leq x)$, as you wrote.

Comment: Since $Y=X^2$ it is a bit odd to ask about independece

Comment: As $Y$ is completely determined by $X$, they are dependent. You have to expand on this observation and then you are done.

Comment: @asdf agreed, but I am asked anyway :D.

Comment: @StubbornAtom can you give a hint how should i expand this fact in order to give a rigorous prove? I stuck in finding the joint pdf or cdf to show the independence, but seems it can't be done by that way.

Comment: Not sure about a rigorous proof of this, maybe someone could provide it later.

Comment: A rigorous proof: $$E(X^2\cdot Y)=\frac15\ne \frac13\cdot\frac13=E(X^2)\cdot E(Y)$$

Comment: And another rigorous proof: $$P(0\leqslant X\leqslant\tfrac12,Y\geqslant\tfrac14)=0\ne\tfrac14\cdot\tfrac12= P(0\leqslant X\leqslant\tfrac12)\cdot P(Y\geqslant\tfrac14)$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\mathbb{P}(X\leq x, Y\leq y)=\mathbb{P}(X\leq x, X^2 \leq y)=\mathbb{P}(X\leq x, -\sqrt{y}\leq X \leq \sqrt{y})$

If $x^2>y$, then we get that $\mathbb{P}(X\leq x, Y\leq y)=\mathbb{P}(-\sqrt{y}\leq X \leq \sqrt{y})=\sqrt{y}$

If $x^2\leq y$, then we get that $\mathbb{P}(X\leq x, Y\leq y)=\mathbb{P}(-\sqrt{y}\leq X \leq x)=\frac{x+\sqrt{y}}{2}$

On the other hand, $\mathbb{P}(X\leq x)\mathbb{P}( Y\leq y)=\mathbb{P}(X\leq x)\mathbb{P}(-\sqrt{y}\leq X\leq \sqrt{y})=\mathbb{P}(X\leq x)\sqrt{y}$

If $x>0$ then $\mathbb{P}(X\leq x)=\frac{1+x}{2} \implies \mathbb{P}(X\leq x)\mathbb{P}( Y\leq y)=\frac{1+x}{2}\sqrt{y}$

If $x\leq 0$ then $\mathbb{P}(X\leq x)=\frac{1-x}{2} \implies \mathbb{P}(X\leq x)\mathbb{P}( Y\leq y)=\frac{1-x}{2}\sqrt{y}$

Comment: thanks very much, this is what i wanted to do.